# Iterate object keys to replace the selected one with desired keys using es6 array functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a requirement to replace the available keys with the desired keys in an object for which I was trying to execute below code, which later I found out to be incorrect usage of filter for desired output. hence I need help in getting the desired results using es6 array functions.

```
const columns = Object.keys(someArray).filter((columnName) => {
      if (someCheck === "somecheck") {
        if (columnName === 'MyName') {
          const newcolumnName = `Pranav`;
          return newcolumnName;
        } else if (columnName === 'YourName') {
          const newcolumnName = `Alex`;
          return newcolumnName;
        }
      } else {
        return (columnName !== 'sometingelse') ? columnName : '';
      }
    }
    );
```

Here the `someArray` is as below:

```
someArray{
  abc:"djfhdjf",
  xyz:"ssss",
  MyName:"onename",
  YourName:"somename",
  sometingelse:'somevalue'
}
```

I am expecting `columns` to be:

```
columns{
  abc:"djfhdjf",
  xyz:"ssss",
  Pranav:"onename",
  Alex:"somename",
  sometingelse:'somevalue'
}
```

Please suggest how can I achieve the above expected output?

**Note: I dont want to use function keyword in callbacks to avoid eslint errors**

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking, or, at least, it's quite vague and can be solved in many different ways. For the sake of giving you a starting point, you may think about combining the **spread operator** (...) with **array.map** instead: https://jsfiddle.net/ve3zgbft/ Otherwise, you may think about combining filter and forEach (remember to delete the older key, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  abc: 'djfhdjf',
  xyz: 'ssss',
  MyName: 'onename',
  YourName: 'somename',
  sometingelse: 'somevalue'
};

const newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
  if (key === 'MyName') {
   acc.newMyName = obj[key];
  } else if (key === 'YourName') {
   acc.newYourName = obj[key];
  } else {
   acc[key] = obj[key];
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log('newObj = ', newObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the wanted keys for replacement and replace the keys by using a new key and eleting the old one.

```js
const
    object = { abc: "djfhdjf", xyz: "ssss", MyName: "onename", YourName: "somename", sometingelse: 'somevalue' },
    replacements = { MyName: 'Pranav', YourName: 'Alex', sometingelse: '' };

Object
    .keys(object)
    .filter(k => k in replacements)
    .forEach(k => {
        object[replacements[k]] = object[k];
        delete object[k];
    });
  
console.log(object);
```

For generating an object, you could map new objects and assign them to a single object.

```js
const
    object = { abc: "djfhdjf", xyz: "ssss", MyName: "onename", YourName: "somename", sometingelse: 'somevalue' },
    replacements = { MyName: 'Pranav', YourName: 'Alex', sometingelse: '' },
    result = Object.assign(...Object
        .entries(object)
        .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k in replacements ? replacements[k] : k]: v }))
    );
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not sure of this but my eslint says "Assignment to property of function parameter 'object'"..

Answer (score 0):

I am running a reduce on the keys of some array starting with an empty object. The ...acc spreads out all the properties in the reduced object. ...{ [keysMap[key] || key]: obj[key] } checks if the current key is present in keysMap.If it is present,it uses that key (keysMap[key]) otherwise it just uses the keys of the existing object.(|| key).Hope that makes sense

```
    const renameKeys = (keysMap, obj) =>
       Object.keys(obj).reduce(
        (acc, key) => ({
          ...acc,
          ...{ [keysMap[key] || key]: obj[key] }
       }),
    {}
  )
  const columns = renameKeys({'MyName':'Pranav','YourName':'Alex'},someArray)
```

Comment: I am running a reduce on the keys of some array starting with an empty object.
The ...acc spreads out all the properties in the reduced object.
...{ [keysMap[key] || key]: obj[key] } checks if the current key is present in keysMap.If it is present,it uses that key (keysMap[key]) otherwise it just uses the keys of the existing object.(|| key).Hope that makes sense

Comment: @anuragb26.. Put your explanation snippet wise(if possible) inside your answer by editing it..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach, a bit long solution, but its on purpose so you can see how to do it simple without too much abstraction:

```
const someArray = {
abc:"djfhdjf",
xyz:"ssss",
MyName:"onename",
YourName:"somename",
sometingelse:'somevalue'
}


let foo = Object.keys(someArray).map(key => {
  if(key === 'MyName') {
    return 'Alex'
  } else if(key === 'YourName') {
    key = 'Pranav'
  }
  return key;
})

let bar = Object.entries(someArray).map((el, i) => {
  el[0] = res[i];
  return el;
})

let baz = r.reduce((acc, el)=>{
  acc[`${el[0]}`] = el[1];
  return acc;
},{})
console.log(baz);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.reduce` like so. It uses a similar idea that Nina proposed by using an object to hold your replacements. Here I have used the spread syntax to add the changed key to the accumulated object, along with it's associated value.

```js
const someArray = {abc: "djfhdjf", xyz: "ssss", MyName: "onename", YourName: "somename", sometingelse: 'somevalue'},
toUse = {MyName: "Pranav", YourName: "Alex"}, // define the keys you want to change and what they should change to

res = Object.keys(someArray).reduce((acc, key) => 
    ({...acc, [key in toUse ? toUse[key] : key]:someArray[key]})
, {});
console.log(res);
```